# window.open with target '_blank' opens a new browser window

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, hyperlink

I am trying to open an link in new browser tab (not in new window).

When I place an link on page like

```
<a href="#" onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank');"> Click Here</a>
```

when user click on link it will open google in new browser tab. That's fine

BUT

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: someURL,
   data: {somedata},
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   success: function (response) {
    window.open('http://www.google.com', '_blank'); // it's always open in new browser window and I want a new tab
   },
   failure: function (response) {
      alert(response);
      return;
   }
});
```

When I try this within an AJAX web method, it always opens it in new browser window; but I want to open it in new tab as it's working for above example.

I understand this is browser specific functionality but somehow I need to accomplish this.

Comment: which browser you are using?

Comment: Mostly Chrome, but our users may be using, IE 9+, FireFox, Safari...

Comment: `var newWindow = window.open("","_blank");` declare this out of that function and then at the after success of ajax `newWindow.location.href = newURL` try that if succeed i want to post it as answer ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Open a URL in a new tab using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4907843/open-a-url-in-a-new-tab-using-javascript)

Comment: @Justcode, it's same as in new window ...

Comment: but have u tried i was having the same issue

Comment: Yes I tried the same you posted in comment above..

Comment: @downvoter I googled alot for it but didn't found any answer. So How can this question have an answer elsewhere.

Comment: add href="javascript:void(0);" on "a" tag
+
@Justcode answer


works like charm

Comment: @jalil glad it helps

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com', '_self');
```

Answer (score 0):

well it is browser specific, i tested it on mozilla and is working fine, but on chrome it open  in new browser window. You can suggest to chrome makers or call ajax synchronus.

use `async:false` will work.

**NOTE:** In IE, open new browser window is default behaviour. user need to set settings explicitly

Comment: on which browser you are using

Answer (score 0):

You have to play  a little trick here.
You have to create a hidden a link tag with target='_blank' and set the href of this link tag on ajax success and then trigger the click of this link tag for eg.

HTML code

```
<a href="#" id="hidden_link" target="_blank">hidden</a>
```

Js code

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: someURL,
  data: {somedata},
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (response) {
   var hiddenLink = $("hidden_link");
   hiddenLink.attr("href",response.href);
   hiddenLink[0].click();  
  },
  failure: function (response) {
    alert(response);
    return;
  }
 });
```

Here is the working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V79qk/) for above code